# Как отменить запрос в interceptor android retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

Имеется такой интерцептор:

```
class AuthToken(context: Context) : Interceptor {
    var cont = context
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val sp = cont.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0)
        val originalRequest:Request? = (if (sp!!.getLong("expires_in", 0) - sp.getLong("time_delta", 0) - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 <= 60) {
            updateToken(chain)
            null
        } else {
            chain.request()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .header("Content-type:", "application/json")
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + cont.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", "")!!)
                    .build()
        })


        if (originalRequest!=null){
            val response = chain.proceed(originalRequest)
            when (response.code) {
                401 -> {
                    updateToken(chain)
                }
                500 -> {
                    Toast.makeText(cont, cont.getString(R.string.server_error_500), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }


            return response
        }else chain.proceed(originalRequest)

    }


    private fun updateToken(request: Interceptor.Chain) {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val dispatcher = Dispatcher()
        dispatcher.maxRequests = 1

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .dispatcher(dispatcher)
                .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()


        client.dispatcher.cancelAll()
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        val api = retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)

        api.getNewToken(ReqAccessToken(cont.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("refresh_token", "")!!)).enqueue(object : Callback<ResNewTokens> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResNewTokens>, response: retrofit2.Response<ResNewTokens>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val editor = cont.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).edit()
                    editor.putString("access_token", Objects.requireNonNull<ResNewTokens>(response.body()).access_token).apply()
                    editor.putString("refresh_token", Objects.requireNonNull<ResNewTokens>(response.body()).refresh_token).apply()
                    editor.putLong("expires_in", response.body()!!.expires_in!!).apply()

                    makeNewCall(request)
                } else {
                    when (response.code()) {
                        401 -> {
                            Singleton.logOut(cont)
                        }

                        500 -> {
                            Toast.makeText(cont, cont.getString(R.string.server_error_500), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResNewTokens>, t: Throwable) {

            }

        })
    }

    private fun makeNewCall(req: Interceptor.Chain): Request {
        return req.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .header("Content-type:", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + cont.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", "")!!)
                .build()
    }
}
```

проблема в этих строках:

```
if (sp!!.getLong("expires_in", 0) - sp.getLong("time_delta", 0) - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 <= 60) {
            updateToken(chain)
            null
        }
```

суть задачи которую я пытаюсь решить - убрать лишний запрос с протухшим токеном который заведомо точно вернет 401 ошибку. Для этого я обернул все в if но не получается нормально это реализовать так как функция `intercept` должна полюбому возвращать `Response` чего не делается в данном условии. Думал сделать чтобы null слался но получается криво. Нужно как-то либо отменить запрос который планировался к посланию либо как-то иначе решить данную проблему но я не придумал как именно :(

### UPDATE:

Вот что пока получилось:

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val sp = cont.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0)
        val originalRequest = if (sp!!.getLong("expires_in", 0) - sp.getLong("time_delta", 0) - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 <= 60) {
            val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

            val dispatcher = Dispatcher()
            dispatcher.maxRequests = 1


            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .dispatcher(dispatcher)
                    .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()


            client.dispatcher.cancelAll()
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
            val api = retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)
            synchronized(this) {
                when {
                    api.getNewToken(ReqAccessToken(cont.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("refresh_token", "")!!)).execute().isSuccessful -> {
                        val responseBody = api.getNewToken(ReqAccessToken(cont.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("refresh_token", "")!!)).execute().body()
                        val editor = cont.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).edit()
                        editor.putString("access_token", Objects.requireNonNull<ResNewTokens>(responseBody).access_token).apply()
                        editor.putString("refresh_token", Objects.requireNonNull<ResNewTokens>(responseBody).refresh_token).apply()
                        editor.putLong("expires_in", responseBody!!.expires_in!!).apply()

                        chain.request()
                                .newBuilder()
                                .header("Content-type:", "application/json")
                                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + cont.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", "")!!)
                                .build()
                    }

                    else->{

                    }
                }
            }



        } else {
            chain.request()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .header("Content-type:", "application/json")
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + cont.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", "")!!)
                    .build()
        }


        val response = chain.proceed(originalRequest)
        when (response.code) {
            401 -> {
                //updateToken(chain)
            }
            500 -> {
                Toast.makeText(cont, cont.getString(R.string.server_error_500), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }


        return response
    }
```

и `val response = chain.proceed(originalRequest)` говорит о том что ждут request. Я то пробовал в if прописать request но его тогда не видно я так понял.

Comment: 1. Используя системное время вы ничего себе не гарантируете - юзер может в любой момент любое время поставить. 2. Вам не нужно обновление токена делать в фоне - делайте его синхронно и возвращайте сразу же обновлённый запрос с новыми токенами.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, перевод времени учитывается, там есть переменная delta которая равна разнице, как сделать синхронно? через authentificator?

Comment: 2. Примерно так: `api.getNewToken().execute()`, `пишем токен из ответа в префы`, `составляем запрос с новым токеном`, `возвращаем его из `updateToken() используя в fun intercept() в качестве возвращаемого значения`,

Comment: проблема в том что в if которое срабатывает когда токен тухлый нужно как-то вернуть request  а вернуть его не получается :(

Comment: Почему не получается? Получите новый токен и повторите код из else вместо null. Главное тут - запрос на новый токен сделать синхронно.

Comment: то есть запрос делать не так как я делаю в коде из вопроса? и о каком else идет речь?

Comment: Вы в процессе обработки результата запроса шлете новый запрос в новом фоновом потоке. Это делать нет смысла и вообще чревато проблемами с многопоточностьюб. Вам надо сделать это просто синхронно как я выше писал. А кол вставляйте туда, где у вас сейчас.  Update и возвращение null

Comment: а синхронно это разве не `synchronized(this)` я так понял что это синхронность? вот эту часть не могу понять куда вы указываете -  `А кол вставляйте туда, где у вас сейчас. Update и возвращение null `

Comment: я вот читаю что `.execute()` используется в синхронных запросах, я его добавил в обновленный вариант реализации

Comment: Я в ответе написал как это у меня сделано - посмотрите. Там 2 API, 2 retrofit-a, 2 OkHttp клиента - один с прикреплением токена и обработкой 401 ошибки - используется для запросов, требующих авторизации, т.е. токена. Второй - не требует токена, используется, для получения токенов.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, то есть вы все-таки получаете ошибку  я так понимаю?

Comment: Да, всё верно. Если вы хотите - можете перед отправкой запроса проверить что токен протух, получить его и только тогда отправить запрос.

Comment: я понял, спасибо большое, буду сейчас изучать :) надеюсь сильно беспокоить не буду :(

Comment: Я обновил ответ, добавив проверку истечения токена. Просто добавьте реализацию `tokenExpired()`

Comment: `tokenExpired()` по-моему используется в session repository? как данная система поймет что токен протух? я ведь никак не сохраняю utc время с сервера? или лучше это использовать вместо sharedPreferences?

Comment: в tokenExpired() может быть любая логика - я лично считаю, что её написать невозможно, т.к. системное время на клиенте под контролем юзера и вообще нет проблемы в редких лишних запросах. В вашем случае можете просто заменить `tokenExpired()` на ваш код: `sp!!.getLong("expires_in", 0) - sp.getLong("time_delta", 0) - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 <= 60`. SessionRepository же в моём ответ - просто обёртка над префами

Comment: я понял, спасибо, буду ковыряться :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас должно получиться что-то вроде такого:

```
//network
val logger = object : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {
    override fun log(message: String) {
        Timber.tag("OkHttp").d(message)
    }
}
val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor(logger)
    .apply {
        level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    }
val okHttpClientCommon = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
    .build()

val authRetrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_IP + BuildConfig.API_URL)
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .client(okHttpClientCommon)
    .build()
val authApi = authRetrofit.create(AuthApi::class.java)

val accessTokenInterceptor = object : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        //we need to set header in any case, as we need to receive JSON response
        //instead of redirect to `/login/ page
        val token = sessionRepository.getAccessToken() ?: ""
        val request =
            chain
                .request()
                .newBuilder()
                .header(
                    ScpConstants.Api.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION,
                    ScpConstants.Api.HEADER_PART_BEARER + token
                )
                .build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}

val unauthAccessTokenInterceptor = object : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        if (tokenExpired()) updateAccessToken()
        val initialRequest = chain.request()
        val initialResponse = chain.proceed(initialRequest)
        if (initialResponse.code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED && sessionRepository.getRefreshToken() != null) {
            updateAccessToken()

            //we need to close response to be able to start new request
            initialResponse.close()
            val authorizedRequest = initialRequest
                .newBuilder()
                .header(
                    ScpConstants.Api.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION,
                    ScpConstants.Api.HEADER_PART_BEARER + tokenResponse.accessToken
                )
                .build()
            return chain.proceed(authorizedRequest)
        } else {
            return initialResponse
        }
    }
}

val accessTokenOkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
    .addInterceptor(accessTokenInterceptor)
    .addInterceptor(unauthAccessTokenInterceptor)
    .build()

//user api
val userRetrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_IP + BuildConfig.API_URL + ScpConstants.Api.Endpoint.USER)
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .client(accessTokenOkHttpClient)
    .build()
```

---

```
fun updateAccessToken() {

    val tokenResponse = authApi
        .getAccessTokenByRefreshTokenSync(
            Credentials.basic(
                BuildConfig.CLIENT_ID,
                BuildConfig.CLIENT_SECRET
            ),
            ScpConstants.Api.GRANT_TYPE_REFRESH_TOKEN,
            sessionRepository.getRefreshToken()!!
        )
        .execute()
        .body()
        ?: throw NullPointerException("Body is null while get accessToken by refreshToken!")
    sessionRepository.setAccessToken(tokenResponse.accessToken)

}
```